# Can't get the right CSS path to a login form field

Tags: python, r, selenium, web-scraping, css-selectors

I'm trying to scrape a web-site where a login is needed. However I can't find a way to get the CSS-Path (or XPath) from the login form correctly.

Here's the login page: https://www.collectandgo.be/cogo/nl/aanmelden

In Chrome:

- With SelectorGadget I can only select "._loadEvent" which is clearly not enough.
- With DevTools I get "#loginName" and "#password" for user name and password fields, but when I use them in Python or R, I get errors saying that this node can't be found.

In Firefox:

- I get the same problem using FireBug. As shown in [this screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAXx5.png), Firefinder can't find any match for "#password".

I'm new to web-scraping so I guess I'm missing something very trivial.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks elements which you are trying is inside frame. so switch to frame before finding them

we can switch over the elements in frames using 3 ways.

By Index
By Name or Id
By Web Element

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);  // for index
driver.switchTo().frame("id or name of the element");
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//path of frame")));
```